# Very Large SharePoint .bat file

Tags: 2007

I discovered a .bat file backup that is very large, 49.7GB, and taking up nearly the entire D: drive.

The path is C:\Program Files\CommVault\Simpana\iDataAgent\JobResults\CV_JobResults\iDataAgent\MS Sharepoint Doc Agent\2\XXX\BACKUP\2

XXX is a unique number to our environment according to [this post](http://sso.forum.commvault.com/forums/thread/22091.aspx).

I really need to clear out some room on this drive but am not sure if I can delete this file.

Should I remove this file or increase the size of the drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use vendor documentation for your backup software [CommVault Simpana](http://www.commvault.com/solutions/enterprise-applications/microsoft-sharepoint) to relocate backup file location to another drive as required.